# Viewing RoR apps in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new at using RoR, and I'm reading some tutorials and everything but it's all basically centered in the development environment on a local machine (http://localhost:3000).

Because I like playing around with pre-made stuff, I was wondering how I would view the application if I uploaded a project from [here](http://opensourcerails.com)? Do I edit the pointers, config? I'm really sorry about this noob question!

Answer (score 0):

To start your app in production simply use:

```
rails server -e production
```

You might want to set up config/database.yml first and run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: But when it's in production, where do I go to view it? /public ? Because so far (looking through all of these gits) I don't see any html/rhtml files in the public dir

Comment: the same address of development , localhost:3000 as default.